# Flask loading new page as if postgres database hadn't updated

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I'm running a website on flask.  When a new page loads any queries to the heroku postgres database occur as if the last commit didn't happen.  Reloading the page will then update the queries.

For example
Load 1 with an empty database

```
Somelist = Users.query.all()
print(somelist)
Somelist(data)
db.session.commit()
$ []
```

Load 2

```
Somelist = Users.query.all()
print(somelist)
Somelist(moredata)
db.session.commit()
$ []
```

Load 3

```
Somelist = Users.query.all()
print(somelist)
Somelist(evenmoredata)
db.session.commit()
$ [data]
```

The site is using postgres on heroku,  Python 3.6, Flask, flask-sqlalchemy.  All queries are doing this regardless of which script they are part of and regardless of whether I run the site on Heroku or locally.  Also regardless of whether the commit occurs inline, in a class method or in a function and regardless of script.

I have tried adding

```
time.sleep(excessivedelay)
```

Before and after the commit and the issue still occurs.
I'm at a bit of a loss.  Any ideas would be great appreciated, thanks.